# Get the last record from each month, from each MATERIAL id after a rolling sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which I need to perform a rolling sum for each material. I've already done it using this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(`ESTOQUE_FINAL`) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY)  as ESTOQUE
FROM bq_trusted.IINV_01
ORDER BY MATERIAL, CALDAY
```

The result is
[in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkdXh.png)

What i need now is to get the results on the red circled values. For each MATERIAL, I need the result of the rolling sum by the end of each month.

I can get those results using the following query, but I have to save the last query on a new table to use it.

```
WITH ESTOQUE_ATUAL AS (
  SELECT IQ.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR ORDER BY CALDAY DESC) AS RN
  FROM bq_trusted.INVENTORY AS IQ
)
SELECT * FROM ESTOQUE_ATUAL WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY MONTH_YEAR
```

How can I achieve this result using only one query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             SUM(ESTOQUE_FINAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY)  as ESTOQUE,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR ORDER BY CALDAY DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM bq_trusted.IINV_01 i
     ) i
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY MATERIAL, CALDAY
```

You can calculate both window functions at the same time.